# Appium Inspector: Request timeout, failed to create session

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

Installed latest version of appium, and get request timeout.
version appium: Appium-1.20.2-4
tried:
change the remote path : /wd/hub

This screenshot of the error, kindly any suggestion solution for this error?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "wdaLaunchTimeout" to increase the timeout.
.
I was also facing the same and after lots of R&D, I got this solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).